# Invoking method does absolutely nothing?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, linked-list

So right now I'm converting an array program into a linked list for my final assignment. I've run into a problem, however, when trying to invoke one of my methods. When the user selects option 3 in ProcessChoice (there is a getChoice() method as well), it goes right back to the main menu. These are the methods associated with that choice. DispItem() and FindItem() are in another class. ProcessChoice() is in the user class.

```
void DispItem() {
    ItemNode current = head;
    current = FindItem();
    if (current == null) {
        System.out.println("\nThe item was not found.\n");
    } else current.DispItem();
}

ItemNode FindItem() {
    ItemNode current = head;
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the ID of the item you are looking for.\n");
    int ID = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (current != null) {
        if (ID == current.GetItemID()) {
            current.DispItem();
        } else System.out.println("Error.");
    }
    return (current);
}

public static void ProcessChoice(int qChoice, InvenLL qMyAcct) {
    if (qChoice == 1) {
        qMyAcct.DispItems();
    } else if (qChoice == 2) {
        qMyAcct.AddItem();
    } else if (qChoice == 3) {
        qMyAcct.DispItem();
    }
    /*else if (qChoice == 4)
                {
                    qMyAcct.ModifyItem();
                }*/
    else if (qChoice == 5) {
        System.out.println("\nYou have exited the program. The item data will now be saved. Good bye!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug it. What happens?

Comment: We haven't done anything with debugging throughout the class. I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Well current, from what I understand about linked lists, is going to start at the head and go through however many items there are to search for the correct one. I could be completely wrong, I feel like I was thrown to the sharks on this.

Comment: Please format your code properly. In java, all method and variable names use `camelCase` - only classes and class-like things use `PascalCase`; the opening brace `{` goes on the _same line_ as the function declaration, control construct, or class declaration; the closing brace should have the same indentation level as the opening line. There are other problems, too, like your use of a large `else if` chain rather than a `switch`, and the overabbreviated variable names.

Comment: @AJMansfield thanks for saying that, it was the first thing that caught my attention, but I didn't want to enforce my code styling preferences to others.

Comment: I'm a little more concerned with fixing my awful code than making it look nicer. I think it's readable for now.

Comment: @SeanDiablo that's wrong and it's a common beginner's mistake. Unreadable code is often cause of missing bugs. That said, I can't wrap my head around your code, I your naming "conventions" don't really help much (tip: don't make names short, it's not '80 anymore, you aren't saving anything by making your code unintelligible). Explain what are `DispItem` and `FindItem` supposed to do, because from my current understanding, nothing much is being done. And what do you mean by `it goes right back to the main menu`?

Comment: And something to get you started: form what I've understood, you want to make linked list. The way it's done is having head, or first element and each element pointing to next element. In your while loop, you're supposed to check if the ID is matching to `current` element id, if not, you should move current pointer to next element. You should also work on fixing the cross calls, it's hard to figure out what's supposed to do when you're cross-calling between the two functions. I suggest you re-evaluate your logic and redesign this class, current one has multiple anti-patterns.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem with your code is the style. Here is what it *should* look like, using the coding conventions for *java*:

```
void dispItem(){
    ItemNode current = head;
    current = findItem();
        if(current == null){
            System.out.println("\nThe item was not found.\n");
        }
        else current.dispItem();
}

ItemNode findItem(){
    ItemNode current = head;
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the ID of the item you are looking for.\n");
    int ID = keyboard.nextInt();
    while(current != null){
        if(ID == current.getItemID()){
            current.dispItem();
        }
        else System.out.println("Error.");
    }
    return (current);

}

public static void processChoice(int qChoice, InvenLL qMyAcct){
    switch(qChoice){
    case 1:
        qMyAcct.dispItems();
        break;
    case 2:
        qMyAcct.addItem();
        break;
    case 3:
        qMyAcct.dispItem();
        break;
    case 4:
        qMyAcct.modifyItem();
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("\nYou have exited the program. The item data will now be saved. Good bye!\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

With stylistic problems out of the way, the logical error becomes more obvious. The *logical* error in your program is right here in this loop:

```
while(current != null){
    if(ID == current.getItemID()){
        current.dispItem();
    }
    else System.out.println("Error.");
}
```

As written, this loop will never terminate, because `current` is never updated inside the loop.

You probably meant to do something like this:

```
while(current != null){
    if(ID == current.getItemID()){
        current.dispItem();
    }
    else System.out.println("Error.");

    current = current.next(); //or whatever function returns the next node.
}
```

However, this still makes no sense. `findItem` should not be printing errors or displaying the list contents; it should be finding the item **and nothing else**. This is a result of mixing your business logic with your application logic.

A proper implementation of this sort of thing would have the `linkedlist` be entirely separate from the menu prompts and stuff. In fact, in the real world one wouldn't be implementing a linked list at all -- one would use a [`java.util.LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). I suspect that that isn't an option, since this is a school assignment. However, you can do the next best thing, and use [`java.util.AbstractSequentialList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html). If that isn't allowed, then implement [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) yourself, or at least pattern your linkedlist implementation on that interface. Beyond that, it would be a SMOP to implement the necessary menu structure.

Comment: I'm guessing the `else` is still wrong, this would output `Error.` for each element not matching the `ID`. What OP probably meant is print `Error.` if element is not found, which should be done after while loop, if `current` is null. Also if the correct element is found, while loop should probably be terminated. Not saying you're wrong, but op needs to clarify their ideas.

Comment: @maremp but that's really just a symptom of a bigger problem, mixing buisness and application logic. I added a section to my answer suggesting how to overcome that problem.

Comment: I've realised that when I took a look at the code, it took me almost 5 minutes to just get an idea of what it's supposed to do and how it's failing at that. About the last edit, I'm guessing that using external classes or interfaces it's probably not an option. At least that was the case at my uni algorithms course this year, for our midterm assignment we had to implement doubly linked list from scratch, no other classes/interfaces were allowed.

Comment: @maremp Even if `AbstractSequentialList` is not allowed, surely implementing the `List` interface without using any external concrete implementations should be allowed? My algorithms course allowed this.

Comment: I'm not sure about explicit prohibition of implementing any interfaces, but none of my schoolmates I've talked to did it, we all created it from scratch. We weren't required to create behaviour like typed list (`List<T>`), but only stored objects inside nodes and cast them to correct type when using them.

Comment: @maremp The casting thing is actually harder, though. It is in fact much easier to just use generics.

Comment: I've used them but most of the class doesn't know about those, I doubt it's easier to use something that you have to learn first.

Answer (score -1):

Your while loop inside FindItem() never reassigns current, seems like it would loop forever. Are you maybe running this inside a try-catch block?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's running inside try-catch? And this should be a comment, not answer.

Comment: This is not running in any sort of try-catch. How would I go about reassigning current?

Comment: I don't have reputation to comment on other peoples posts. I was thinking there would be an exception if it was an infinite loop, was wrongly thinking it was a recursive loop. Showing more code could maybe help.

Comment: Since when do infinite loops throw an exception? And even at infinite recursion, `StackOverflowError` won't be caught.

Comment: If you know what code you'd need to see to help me out I'd be more than willing.

Comment: You can put println messages in the code to see how far it goes before going back to menu. Start with just before qMyAcct.DispItem(); in ProcessChoice() to see if it even reaches that option. It almost feels like you are maybe running and old copy of the program where that option was commented out, sure that it compiles without errors?

Comment: Well I went ahead and re-javac'd everything because your question made me wonder if it was true and now option 3 is able to be selected. However, it runs an infinite loop of the item being displayed. Where do I fix that?